# Updating user fields after order completion

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can anyone help me with this code.  I had it working at one time but due to some changes in WooCommerce it no longer works.

The code must run on order completion and update the users meta field based on how many credits they earned from the purchase.

Thanks

```
 function custom_update_user_credits( $order_id = NULL ) {
    global $woocommerce;


    // Set product ids and credits

    $product_id1 = 80;
    $ad_credits1 = 10;

    $product_id2 = 82;
    $ad_credits2 = 20;

    $product_id3 = 83;
    $ad_credits3 = 30;


    $customer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', TRUE );
    $user_credit = (int) get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'wpcf-ad_credits', TRUE );

    if ( $order_id && 0 != $customer_id ) :
        $order = &new WC_Order( $order_id );


        // Get the order items

        $items = get_product( $post->ID );

        // Loop through the order items looking for the right products
        foreach($items as $item) :


            // Credits

            if ( $item['id'] == $product_id1 ) :
            $credit_total = $user_credit + $ad_credits1;

            elseif ( $item['id'] == $product_id2 ) :
            $credit_total = $user_credit + $ad_credits2;

            elseif ( $item['id'] == $product_id3 ) :
            $credit_total = $user_credit + $ad_credits3;

            update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'wpcf-ad_credits', $credit_total, $user_credit );                       

            endif;

        endforeach;

    endif;

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_update_user_credits' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question more than once while trying to solve my own issue. This may be a little late but here's how I'm using woocommerce product data to update custom user meta.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'CUSTOM_AFTER_PURCHASE_FUNCTION' );

function CUSTOM_AFTER_PURCHASE_FUNCTION( $order_id ) {

    // Get user's ID
    $order_user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );

    // If there's a valid order and user continue
    if ( $order_id && $order_user_id != 0 ) {

        // Get $order
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

        // Loop through $order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

            // Get product info using $item['product_id']
            $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);

            // Get $sku ... I explode it into an array because I have info mapped to it
            $sku_array = explode('-', $product->get_sku());
            if ( $sku_array[0] == 'CR' )
                $credits_to_add = $sku_array[1] * $item['qty'] + $credits_to_add;
        }

        $new_credit_count = users_current_credits() + $credits_to_add; // Uses custom function to check user's current credits
        update_user_meta( $order_user_id, 'contest-credits', $new_credit_count );

    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps